# Split MS Access table into parts and export into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access table of about 50000 records which I require to split into preferably 3 parts and export these parts into individual excel files or sheets using VBA.

I require this, as these Excel files are used elsewhere where the maximum number of records in a file can only be about 20000 records.

I have played around with the docmd.transferspreadsheet method but can't seem to split them.

Any ideas or help appreciated.

Edit: This table that I am working with consists of columns: Part Number (made of various characters which is unique), description, price,comments. It does not have a ID number say from 1 till 50000 each relating to a record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ExportChunks()
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim ssql As String
Dim maxnum As Long
Dim numChunks As Integer

Dim qdef As QueryDef

ssql = "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM BigTable"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(ssql)

maxnum = rs.Fields(0).Value  'total number of records

'add 0.5 so you always round up:
numChunks = Round((maxnum / 20000) + 0.5, 0)

On Error Resume Next 'don't break if Chunk_1 not yet in QueryDefs

ssql = "SELECT TOP 20000 * FROM BigTable"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "Chunk"
Set qdef = New QueryDef
qdef.SQL = ssql
qdef.Name = "Chunk"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Append qdef
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Chunk_1", "C:\00_Projekte_temp\Chunk_1.xlsx"

For i = 2 To numChunks
    ssql = "SELECT TOP 20000 * FROM BigTable WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP " & (i - 1) * 20000 & " ID FROM BigTable)"
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chunk")
    qdef.SQL = ssql
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chunk_" & i)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, qdef.Name, "C:\00_Projekte_temp\" & qdef.Name & ".xlsx"
Next i

End Sub
```

What does it do? First it calculates how many chunks you'll need, then creates queries that will take the first 20,000 records, then the next and so forth, and lastly exports each chunked query to an Excel file.

**Edit:** Amended to onyl create one query that gets overwritten in each iteration and exported to a new Excel file.

Comment: Oh, instead of ID you can of course use "PartnNumber" as column identifier.

Comment: Did try this and the code seems to run perfectly fine however only a 'Chunk_1' is created with 20000 records, which is great, but chunk_2 and chunk_3 aren't found anywhere.

Comment: Funny! After I append the QueryDef, my `qdef`object became invalid. :-?
I amended the code above, should work fine now.

Comment: I take it that should be SELECT TOP 20000, as this now creates numerous chunk files each with 4 rows :/

Comment: Also, Chunk_1 appears in my queries and the path folder and can be viewed easily however the other chunks don't appear in my folder, although they do in the created queries tab however just hang when you click them to open.

Comment: I just extended my table a bit to hold 3360 records and created chunks of 400 each. Worked as expected; I get 9 Chunk queries and 9 Excel files. Actually, creating all these queries is superfluous, since all you need are the Excel files. I have therefore adapted the code to always overwrite the previous query once it has been exported to Excel.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably have a unique numeric *Id* on the table, create these three queries and export these one by one:

```
 Select * From YourTable Where Id Mod 3 = 0

 Select * From YourTable Where Id Mod 3 = 1

 Select * From YourTable Where Id Mod 3 = 2
```

**Option: Add virtual row number:**

Create ans ave a query like this:

```
SELECT RowCounter([ProductKey],False) AS Id, *
FROM YourTable
WHERE (RowCounter([ProductKey],False) <> RowCounter("",True));
```

using the function below. Then adjust the three queries to use the new query.

```
Public Function RowCounter( _
  ByVal strKey As String, _
  ByVal booReset As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal strGroupKey As String) _
  As Long

' Builds consecutive RowIDs in select, append or create query
' with the possibility of automatic reset.
' Optionally a grouping key can be passed to reset the row count
' for every group key.
'
' Usage (typical select query):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' Usage (with group key):
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False,CStr[GroupID])) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) <> RowCounter("",True));
'
' The Where statement resets the counter when the query is run
' and is needed for browsing a select query.
'
' Usage (typical append query, manual reset):
' 1. Reset counter manually:
'   Call RowCounter(vbNullString, False)
' 2. Run query:
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable;
'
' Usage (typical append query, automatic reset):
'   INSERT INTO tblTemp ( RowID )
'   SELECT RowCounter(CStr([ID]),False) AS RowID, *
'   FROM tblSomeTable
'   WHERE (RowCounter("",True)=0);
'
' 2002-04-13. Cactus Data ApS. CPH
' 2002-09-09. Str() sometimes fails. Replaced with CStr().
' 2005-10-21. Str(col.Count + 1) reduced to col.Count + 1.
' 2008-02-27. Optional group parameter added.
' 2010-08-04. Corrected that group key missed first row in group.

  Static col      As New Collection
  Static strGroup As String

  On Error GoTo Err_RowCounter

  If booReset = True Then
    Set col = Nothing
  ElseIf strGroup <> strGroupKey Then
    Set col = Nothing
    strGroup = strGroupKey
    col.Add 1, strKey
  Else
    col.Add col.Count + 1, strKey
  End If

  RowCounter = col(strKey)

Exit_RowCounter:
  Exit Function

Err_RowCounter:
  Select Case Err
    Case 457
      ' Key is present.
      Resume Next
    Case Else
      ' Some other error.
      Resume Exit_RowCounter
  End Select

End Function
```

Comment: The table I am working with does not have a unique Numeric ID. Edited my original question to clarify its contents.

Comment: So I deserve a downvote? Thanks. The quick workaround, however, is to add an autonumber field to the table, or to write the records to a new table with an autonumber - would take only a second or so.

Comment: Would not want to add a autonumber field, as code referencing this table and its attributes would be affected elsewhere (or so I believe to my knowledge), however will keep in mind as an option.Writing to a new table, didn't think of that, will try that out with your code, thanks. Not sure who downvoted you, sure wasn't me :)

Comment: OK. The "chunk method" is perfectly valid, but you can also add a virtual row id. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a criteria by witch you part the data, have this partition done by a query, set of queries, or a parameterized query, in witch you replace the parameter by code, using the query's SQL property and VBA `Replace()` function.

If you have no criteria, create one in a temp table:

1. Insert all data from table to a temp table, add a Boolean field `Exported`, default value `False`;
2. Create query `MyQuery` **with a specific order** (probably on primary key), so that you have an object with all data you want to work with:

   ```
   SELECT TOP 20000 * FROM TempTable WHERE Exported = FALSE ORDER BY [Part Number]
   ```
3. Export the data in `MyQuery` to Excel;
4. Set the records in `MyQuery` to `TRUE`:

   ```
   UPDATE MyQuery SET Exported = TRUE
   ```

Until the `MyQuery` is empty, Then delete `TempTable`, or it's contents.