# MS Access Hangs on docmd.transferspreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I grabbed some export code from @LocEngineer (thank you!) from this thread here: [Split MS Access table into parts and export into Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331859/split-ms-access-table-into-parts-and-export-into-excel-using-vbaAccess) But after implementation access will hang indefinitely when it hits the last line of the loop to export the next chunk. Does anyone have ideas why this would happen? Everything seems to be functioning correctly otherwise.. Any insight is very appreciated i am still learning my way around VBA.
[MASTER] is the table to be broken in 25000 rows per excel export.[MaterialNumber] is not unique and contains duplicates in the table.

```
Sub ExportChunks()
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim ssql As String
Dim maxnum As Long
Dim numChunks As Integer

Dim qdef As QueryDef

ssql = "SELECT COUNT([Material Number]) FROM MASTER"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(ssql)

maxnum = rs.Fields(0).Value  'total number of records

'add 0.5 so you always round up:
numChunks = Round((maxnum / 25000) + 0.5, 0)

On Error Resume Next 'don't break if Chunk_1 not yet in QueryDefs

ssql = "SELECT TOP 25000 * FROM MASTER"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "Chunk"
Set qdef = New QueryDef
qdef.SQL = ssql
qdef.Name = "Chunk"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Append qdef
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Chunk_1", "K:\Public\MDM\PMD\Chunk_1.xlsx"

For i = 2 To numChunks
    ssql = "SELECT TOP 25000 * FROM MASTER WHERE [Material Number] NOT IN (SELECT TOP " & (i - 1) * 25000 & " [Material Number] FROM MASTER)"
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chunk")
    qdef.SQL = ssql
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chunk_" & i)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, qdef.Name, "K:\Public\MDM\PMD\" & qdef.Name & ".xlsx"
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider assigning and releasing the same querydef inside the loop especially since you can potentially have hundreds of *Chunk_i* queries. No need to `Append`, `Delete`, or `Refresh`.

Specifically, save a query named *Chunk* beforehand with anything like `SELECT 1 FROM MASTER`, then update its SQL in code, releasing each time:

```
ssql = "SELECT TOP 25000 * FROM MASTER"
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chunk")    ' ASSIGN SAVED QUERY OBJECT
qdef.SQL = ssql                            ' UPDATE ITS SQL
Set qdef = Nothing                         ' RELEASE TO SAVE

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                          "Chunk", "K:\Public\MDM\PMD\Chunk_1.xlsx"

For i = 2 To numChunks
    ssql = "SELECT TOP 25000 * FROM MASTER WHERE [Material Number]" _ 
            & " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " & (i - 1) * 25000 & " [Material Number] FROM MASTER)"

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Chunk")  ' ASSIGN SAVED QUERY OBJECT
    qdef.SQL = ssql                          ' UPDATE ITS SQL
    Set qdef = Nothing                       ' RELEASE TO SAVE

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                              "Chunk", "K:\Public\MDM\PMD\Chunk_" & i & ".xlsx"

Next i
```

Comment: I think i understand, although when i try this, it exports a chunk_1, then freezes on export for all subsequent chunks. EDIT: the completed chunk_1 is wont open either "format or file extension is not correct"

Comment: Comment out the `TransferSpreadsheet` line and see if loop finishes. If no issue there, try latest Excel version: [`acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acspreadsheettype). Finally, *Public* in folder name feels like an internet folder like Dropbox, OneDrive, or GoogleDrive (which should be avoided and especially never run Access in these folders). Try pointing to local folders to avoid network issues.

Comment: It completes after commenting out the transferspreadsheet line in the loop. When i check the Chunk query last used though it reads "SELECT TOP 25000 *
FROM MASTER
WHERE (((MASTER.[Material Number]) Not In (SELECT TOP 725000 [Material Number] FROM MASTER)));

Comment: Tried latest excel  - in continues to freeze on chunk 2.

Comment: Ok. Loop iterated to 29. Once again, did you try running locally on hard disk drives (not internet folders)? Simply move change path. It will only be 30 Excel workbooks with 25k rows.

Comment: Yes just changed path to my documents on C drive, no dice, freezes up immediately. I cannot understand why!

Comment: Hmmmm...is Access running on hard disk CPU drive - not internet folder, not thumb or external HDs? And how are you calling this sub?

Comment: Running off my C drive, nothing! Same issues crashes right at chunk2! I am very confused. Calling the sub from a single button on a form. "run" starts the export..